# K2 auto-complete contrl can't auto complete

Tags: k2

I am learning use K2 Designer to develop a simple device management software.

I want to use the Auto-Complete contrl when the device id input.

I have set a SmartObject and a method to get the device ids and set them as the data source.

The SQL stored procedure is :

```sql
...
  SELECT DEVICE_ID FROM Device_Master
...
```

But when I run to test, I find it can't realize auto-complete.

I want to know why it doesn't work and how to solve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be multiple reasons for this.

1. Your SmartObject cannot execute list method - Check if you can execute the SmartObject's list method in K2 Management.
2. You did not initialize the auto complete control - Try initializing the control when view is initialized.

Comment: Thanks. I have solved this problem last month. My problem happened in control initialzing. The list control populated failed, so there was no data.